# Disincentivising duplicate answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, user-incentives

I have recently noticed this happen on a number of occasions.

Either an answer very similar an existing one (no improvement), or a copy of an existing one is posted to a question, then the answerer downvotes the original answer. If they're lucky, and their answer gets accepted (it's on top) they get +14rep.

<del>Would it be possible to prevent answers similar to an existing one</del>, or has this been explored already? *It's probably too hard to algorithmically distinguish copies from improvements.*

Alternatively, would it make sense to disincentivise this activity by **raising the answer downvote penalty** (to 10~20) for users who have answered the same question?
Or to order similar answers ascending by time?

Comment: you can probably share some example of what you think duplicate answers?

Comment: No. Voting is not a reward system, there is no penalty. You do not upvote to give someone reputation points, you do not downvote something to take them away. You vote up if something is good, you vote down if something is bad as a quality indicator. What happens as a result of that simple neutral curation action, that is not up to us. It is a site mechanism. If by some piece of black magic it could be proven that an answer was posted with ill intent, then whatever penalty is applied is in no way related to voting.

Comment: Your actions got completely out of hand here. You were told by *several* contributors (in now-deleted comments) not to vandalize your posts, and they each rolled back the edits. But yet you kept doing it. You were so persistent on rolling back edits that I literally had to play a game of whack-a-mole to restore this question before locking it. At nearly 10k reputation, you should know better. I don't know what problem you've had that's made you so angry, but feel free to ask a new question about it, raise a flag, or get over it.

Answer (score 7):

> Would it be possible to prevent answers similar to an existing one, or has this been explored already?

Sometimes similar answers are needed, because one answer has a fatal flaw that can't be simply fixed with an edit (or maybe the original author is not amenable to the change, or the new poster simply wants to post their own **correct** answer)

> would it make sense to disincentivise this activity by raising the answer downvote penalty (to 10~20) for users who also have an answer to the same question?

Users who answer a question are supposedly knowledgeable about the question's subject matter, so they are well equipped to judge the other answers quality. "Tactical" voting notwithstanding, we shouldn't do anything else to deter downvotes.

> Or to order similar answers ascending by time?

Similar answers are not necessarily duplicate answers. They can be similar but fundamentally different.

Comment: @pete That's subjective though, and a call that we'd need manual moderation to make. The last thing we need is another time sink for mods. I'm also not sure this is even necessary. If someone posts a C&p'd answer after another answer, I've seen many cases where they get called out and downvoted. People are quick to call out plagiarism. The system seems to already work fine.

Comment: One other scenario, is where the question was so basic, and probably so duplicated, that the solution is so common everyone literally answers with the same code or very similar code.